# Gatling configure base url in configuration file

Tags: scala, maven, gatling

I want to configure the base url of my gatling simulation in the configuration file. So that I can easy switch between test and live system.

I works fine when I configure it in the simulation-scala file with:

```
val httpConf = http
        .baseURL("http://computer-database.herokuapp.com")
```

If I remove the line above and configure it in the config (gatling.conf) file with:

```
gatling {
   http {
     baseUrls = "http://localhost8080/baserate"
     ...
```

I get the following error and my scenario does not work because the base url is empty.

```
09:57:26.352 [ERROR] i.g.c.c.GatlingConfiguration$ - Your gatling.conf file is outdated, some properties have been renamed or removed.
Please update (check gatling.conf in Gatling bundle, or gatling-defaults.conf in gatling-core jar).
Enabled obsolete properties:'gatling.http.baseUrls' was removed, use HttpProtocol.
```

Is it still possible in the current version of gatling to configure the base url outside of the

My version is the gatling-maven-plugin:2.1.2.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved this by creating a application.properties file in /test/resources/ with

```
baseUrl=http://www.example.com
```

I changed my simulation like this:

```
import com.typesafe.config._
class BasicSimulation extends Simulation {
   val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
   val baseUrl = conf.getString("baseUrl")
   val httpConf = http.baseURL(baseUrl)
```

Comment: this is the recommended way to externalize the script variables. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can also create a **singleton object** and expose it in any gatling simulation class.

Imagine a singleton object called Configuration in Configuration.scala like this one :

```
object Configuration {
  val BaseUrl = "http://www.dummyurl.com"
}
```

This should reduce code in your simulation class

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class MySimulation extends Simulation {

  val HttpConf = http
    .baseURL(Configuration.BaseUrl)

  ...
}
```

Just resolve package definitions and imports if needed and *voila*.

*Note: Since **val** means immutable property we should name it with a first uppercase letter*

Comment: You can even get the base URL first from a system property: `val BaseUrl = System.getProperty("baseURL", "http://www.dummyurl.com")`

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it yourself through various ways (System properties, environment variables, custom config files...) but this is not a Gatling built-in anymore.